# Prove there is a rational q so that $|q-\sqrt{2}| < d - c$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Suppose $c < d$.
Prove there is a $q \in Q$ so that $|q-\sqrt{2}| < d - c$

I began this proof by setting $c=1, d=2$, and consequently, $q=\sqrt{2}$. However, my professor informed me that proofs need to satisfy general cases, which makes sense.

Then, I created the inequality $-\alpha<q-\sqrt{2}<\alpha$ with $\alpha$ being arbitrary. Because $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, $i=q-\sqrt{2}$ must be, so we have $-\alpha<i<\alpha$. This process seems typical of similar problems, but I do not know how to complete the proof. I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: You could probably use facts surrounding the rational approximations of irrational numbers. For example, take the number given by the first $n$ digits of the decimal expansion of $\sqrt{2}$. This number is rational and also a decent approximation of $\sqrt{2}$...

Comment: Would this be a contrapositive proof?

Comment: Do you know that "given any two distinct real numbers there lies a rational number between them"? If yes then note that there is a $q\in\mathbb{Q} $ between $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}+d-c$ and you are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the number $x(n)$ represented by the first $n$ digits in the decimal expansion of $\sqrt{2}$. For example, $x(1) = 1$, $x(2) = 1.4$, $x(3) = 1.41$ and so on. Each $x(n)$ is rational since its decimal expansion is finite, and we can see that as $n$ becomes large, $x(n)$ becomes a better and better approximation of $\sqrt{2}$.

To analyze how good these approximations are, note the following inequalities:
$$\begin{align*}\sqrt{2} - x(1) = 0.4142\dots & < 1, \\ \sqrt{2} - x(2) = 0.0142\dots & < 1/10, \\ \sqrt{2} - x(3) = 0.0042\dots & < 1/10^2, \end{align*}$$
and so on. Try using this pattern (and be sure to prove it really *is* a pattern) to show that with sufficiently large $n$, the approximation gets as good as you like (without being equal to $\sqrt{2}$).

Comment: The below is ore similar to my own logic, but I am very interested to hear the rest of your proof. Would you care to expand a bit more? Thank you!

Comment: The point is that $$\sqrt{2} - x(\lceil \log_{1/10}(d - c) \rceil + 1) < (1/10)^{\lceil \log_{1/10}(d - c) \rceil} \leq (1/10)^{\log_{1/10}(d - c)} = d - c.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, meaning that between any two real numbers $a$ and $b$, there is a rational number $c$ where $a < c < b$.

Suppose that c < d and $|q-\sqrt{2}|<d-c$. Note $d$ and $c$ are real numbers, so $d-c$ is also a real number. Denote $d-c$ as $a$. Then
\begin{align}
      & -a < q-\sqrt{2} < a \\
      & -a + \sqrt{2} < q < a + \sqrt{2} 
\end{align}
$-a + \sqrt{2}$ and $a + \sqrt{2}$ are real numbers, so we know that there must be a rational between them, and we can let $q$ be such rational number.

Comment: Review your first paragraph and you should have "between any two real numbers".

Comment: whoops! Fixed it.

Comment: I knew a rational number $q$ existed between any two natural numbers, but I did not know that a $q$ existed between any two real numbers. Thank you for the proof!